# Добавить в регулярку проверку на кириллические символы до @

Tags: php, javascript, регулярные-выражения

Привет.
Есть такое регулярное выражение:

```
((([a-zA-Z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-zA-Z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-zA-Z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-zA-Z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-zA-Z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-zA-Z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-zA-Z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-zA-Z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?
```

Не силен в регулярках.
Нужно исключить адреса вида привет@mail.ru.
Есть возможность просто дописать представленную мной регулярку?
Работаю с h5validate.js , возможно, кто-то уже сталкивался.

Comment: Но зачем? Максимальная проверка мыла на клиенте, это `^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-z]+$` всё остальное пустое.

Comment: Ну, к сожалению, нужно, вернее хотят))

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу сам))

Меняем все совпадения `\u00A0-\uD7FF` до @ на `\u00A0-\u03FF\u0500-\uD7FF`.